# What does it do? #define pulseHigh(pin) {digitalWrite(pin, HIGH); digitalWrite(pin, LOW);

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I can undersand if it was only the `digitalWrite(pin, HIGH)` but what does the `digitalWrite(pin, LOW)` do?
When the code is on the setup function it uses
`pulseHigh(RESET);`
`pulseHigh(W_CLK);`
that what it does is to set the RESET and W_CLK HIGH. So what is the use of the `digitalWrite(pin, LOW)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the context of this definition but I would imagine that it is meant to do exactly what it says: create a [pulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse_%28signal_processing%29) on the given output pin. What is a high pulse if not a quick change from low to high to low?

```
#define pulseHigh(pin) {digitalWrite(pin, HIGH); digitalWrite(pin, LOW);
```

Would simply be a shorter way of writing

```
digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);
digitalWrite(pin, LOW);
```

to the pins named `RESET` and `W_CLK` that are defined elsewhere and probably serve to reset a micro-controller and set the clock/period/pace in some communication protocol.

By making it a definition, you avoid repeating `digitalWrite` numerous times throughout the code.

Comment: in the code the pulseHigh is used only to `digitalWrite(pin,HIGH)`
But why in the code is used both `digitalWrite(pin,HIGH)` and `digitalWrite(pin, LOW)`?
I guess it could be used as `#define pulseHigh(pin) {digitalWrite(pin, HIGH); }`( i dont know of the syntax is correct)

Comment: @Andreas I don't understand what you mean. When you call `pulseHigh(pin)`, the `pin` will be set high and then low very quickly (as fast as possible because there's no delay in between the `digitalWrite`s). It's always two write operations.

Comment: I got your point. You are right. This is how it works in the code as well. 
Thank you for your answer. I appreciate your time